# Creating a search box which hides all possible results until a search word matches an item in the list

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, search

What I would like to do has been called unlogic and almost impossible to do by my colleagues, and that's why I have turned to you guys/girls.

What I would like to do is, in my simple not-programmer mind, pretty straight forward.

What I have is a list of client numbers (001, 002, 003...) that are actually links to another page in my App. So without the searchbox I would have the following:

```
<a href="http...">Client 001</a>
<a href="http...">Client 002</a>
<a href="http...">Client 003</a>
```

The problem here is that the list of clients could run up to hundreds in the future, so my goal is to hide these client links and let the clients look their number up in a search box.

What my colleague made afterwards was really cool but I would like to have the reverse effect. What he made is that as soon as you start typing the list below the search box would get smaller and smaller until the entry matches one of the items in the list. This way a client can tap on his number very easily.

The problem however is, is that I do not want to see a list with all my clients from the beginning. I would like to see that there is only the search box without a visible list of clients. And if I would put '001' in the search box that the item would appear under the box as a link.

I know this is probably very confusing so I made a paint image (which looks stupid I know) of what I am trying to achieve. I hope you guys can help me.

[image]

Thanks a lot for taking your time to look at this!

This is how it currently looks: http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/3310/

Comment: "What my colleague made afterwards was really cool ", can you send what he made so we can make it work the way you want it to!

Comment: Best luck SO doesn't allow more than 5 tags... :)

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the quick responses, what my colleague made looks exactly like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/3310/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what your colleague made used search criteria, why not make default search criteria as empty string?
In that way there should be 0 matches initially as there are no empty clients and dropdown would be empty.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand your solution, which is more my error then it is yours btw! Maybe it would help if I gave you this link: http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/3310/

This is exactly what my colleague made

Comment: Correction, apparently my colleague DOES understand what your saying and he's looking at it right now!

Comment: You could also simply hide td initialy and make it visible again if search length is more then 1, that works fine as well.

Comment: Raimonds you're the best!

Comment: One question still, the only problem that will remain resistent is the fact that as soon as I, as a client, type in '1' it will show every single client number that has a '1' in it. Is it possible to add a function which makes it so that it will only show the lines that meet the search EXACTLY. Instead of showing all the results that consist the given number in the beginning, middle or end of the line.

Comment: I believe there is better way of doing it, but this still works
http://jsfiddle.net/6u732q62/1/

Comment: Great! Can I hire you? ;)